# 2960 x Switches Stacking

Tags: cisco, stacking, switching-modes

can we have POE & NON POE Switches Stacked in on loop Exp( 2 nos of 2960 X 48 FPDL and 2 nos of 2960x  24 Port TDL

Comment: Yes there are no problems stacking different models.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are no problems stacking different models as long as they run the same IOS version.

Comment: As long as they are all running the same IOS version.

Comment: @RonMaupin Fixed.